# Why does my mouse get stuck in the upper left corner in a multi-monitor setup?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

When I move the mouse between monitors (specifically between monitor 2 and 1) and the mouse crosses the top left of the right screen (as its moving left) - it always gets stuck there.

Same thing happens when I try to drag a window across as well.  Is this a feature?  Bug? What is the purpose of it?  Any way to turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

If your monitors aren't the exact same resolution, or their arrangement is off-set in the display properties then you will have corners that don't line up, so the cursor can hit the edge.

Example 1 (different resolutions):

[image]

Example 2 (monitor alignment is off-set):

[image]

Comment: My monitors all have exactly the same resolution.  And there are no offsets that I can see - they line up in the Resolutions dialog.  Is there a way to check for sure?